# How to share ionic app to clients?

Tags: ionic-framework

What is the best way to share an ionic app to clients in our time?

I was using [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) service. It works great for me but it is not easy for clients. I should explain every time what should they do to run APK file for example.

Comment: I use hockeyapp (https://hockeyapp.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic provides Ionic View for iOS & Android

https://ionicframework.com/pro/view

You can push your source code to their server and it is built automatically, and gives you a code to hand out to clients.